# How to replace only first two occurrences of a character from a string in pyspark dataframe column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe df containing dates in string format in column - DTC like this -

```
DTC
11 AUG 2012 10:12
AUG 2012 10:20
13 AUG 2012 10:22
```

I want to replace first two spaces with hyphen for all dates in the column like this -

```
DTC
11-AUG-2012 10:12
AUG-2012 10:20
13-AUG-2012 10:22
```

Any suggestion ? Please note there are some partial dates in the column as well, so cant convert it to date data type which makes it null & I will loose the data. I want to preserve partial dates as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the date with `to_date` using format `"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"` and then format it with your desired format `"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"` like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

new_df = df\
    .withColumn("date", f.to_timestamp(f.col("DTC"), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"))\
    .withColumn("DTC", f.date_format(f.col("date"), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"))\
    .drop("date")
```

Another probably less generic approach would be to edit the string directly. One way at it is to use `split` with a limit of 3 fields and `concat_ws`:

```py
new_df = df.withColumn("DTC", f.concat_ws("-", f.split("DTC", " ", 3)))
```

Comment: This is probably the right approach. But you probably want `HH:mm` as time seems to be in 24h format.

Comment: @Oli - Can't use this approach as there could be partial dates in the columns & to_timestamp method will make it null & I will loose the data. Hence it has to be handled as string. I want to preserve even partial dates.

Comment: Right, when you say partial date, what are the possible patterns?

Comment: partial dates means having only month & year or even only year.

Comment: I added another answer. This one might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of "partial" dates, as mentioned in the comments of the other answer, `to_timestamp` would set them to `null`. In that case, I would use some regex. For instance, in the code below, I extract everything before the last space (`date` column). Then I extract everything after the last space (`time` column). Finally I concat them after replacing spaces by hyphens in the date. Note that I trim the date to get rid of the trailing space.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '11 AUG 2012 10:12'),
    (2, 'AUG 2012 10:20'),
    (3, '2012 11:11')
], ['id', 'DTC'])

df\
    .withColumn("date", f.regexp_extract("DTC", "^.* ", 0))\
    .withColumn("time", f.regexp_extract("DTC", " [^ ]*$", 0))\
    .withColumn("DTC", f.concat(f.regexp_replace(f.trim("date"), " ", "-"), "time"))\
    .show()
```

which yields:

```
+---+-----------------+-----------+------+
| id|              DTC|       date|  time|
+---+-----------------+-----------+------+
|  1|11-AUG-2012 10:12|11 AUG 2012| 10:12|
|  2|   AUG-2012 10:20|   AUG 2012| 10:20|
|  3|       2012 11:11|       2012| 11:11|
+---+-----------------+-----------+------+
```

You may then drop the `date` and `time` columns.

Comment: Good one for the given pattern but I want a generalise one to handle even cases like '11 AUGUST 2012 10:12:11' or 8 AUGUST 2012 10:12:11' or 'AUGUST 8 2012 10:12:11'

Comment: I simplified the first pattern. Now, I extract everything before the space and consider that as the date.